# AngularJS $http returns null data, status -1

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I'm new to Node.js and AngularJS. I'm using MEAN stack to develop a website which access webservices defined. When I use `$http`, it always returns null data. Here are my snippets:

vendor.service.js file:

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('app')
    .factory('VendorService', Service);




function Service($http, $q) {
    var service = {};
    //Store
    service.GetCurrent = GetCurrent;//st_details
return service;

    function GetCurrent() {
        return $http('http://localhost:3000/api/vendors/st_details').then(handleSuccess, handleError);
    }
function handleSuccess(res) {
        alert('hi3');
        alert(res.data);
        return res.data;
    }

    function handleError(res) {
        alert('hi2');
        alert(JSON.stringify(res));
        return $q.reject(res.data);
    }
}

})();
```

The response is:

```
{
  "data": null,
  "status": -1,
  "config":
  {
    "method": "GET",
    "transformRequest": [null],
    "transformResponse": [null],
    "url": "http://localhost:3000/api/vendors/st_details",
    "headers":
    {
      "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
      "Authorization": "Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiI1OWRlMjY5Y2UyMzY3NGMyMWQzNDNkNWYiLCJpYXQiOjE1MTY5MzU5NTUsImV4cCI6MTUxNjk3OTE1NX0.F9p9n9lMIgABKjv7CsAgzlxg7NtOzU6R1CDOsD6lBbI"
    }
  },
  "statusText": ""
}
```

I don't know how to print req json before sending. Also, it is working fine from Boomerang but not from the page.

Could you please help me on this?

Comment: Can you ensure the backend receives the request and returns appropriate data? The code looks overall "okay".

Comment: Thanks Philipp! But the backend is working fine when I checked with Boomerang chorme extension.

Comment: Have you tried calling your backend like so:
`$http('/api/vendors/st_details')`. I assume angular adds the baseUrl on its own again.

Comment: Yes, this is working when my services and app are on same port. But I wanted to separate the app and services. So running services on 3000 port and app is running on 4000 port.

Comment: var request = require('request'); in one of the other controller is working fine. But I'm unable to use this request in the vendor.service.js. Can anyone help me. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

Unwrap the promise inside the controller instead of the service. Just return the `http` req in the service.

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('app')
    .factory('VendorService', Service);

function Service($http, $q) {
    var service = {};
    //Store
    service.GetCurrent = GetCurrent;//st_details
return service;

    function GetCurrent() {
        return $http('http://localhost:3000/api/vendors/st_details')
    }

}
```

your controller should be.

```
VendorService.GetCurrent().then(handleSuccess, handleError);

function handleSuccess(res) {
    alert('hi3');
    alert(res.data);
    return res.data;
}

function handleError(res) {
    alert('hi2');
    alert(JSON.stringify(res));
    return $q.reject(res.data);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! It made no difference in code flow. Also the output is same.